# How do I bind a WPF ComboBox to a List<Objects> in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I'm having issues binding a WPF ComboBox in XAML.

**Here is my object definition and collection:**

```
public class AccountManager
{
   public long UserCode { get; set; }
   public string UserName { get; set; }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{    
   public List<AccountManager> AccountManagers;
}
```

**Here is the XAML definition of my ComboBox:**

```
ComboBox Name="cbTestAccountManagers"
          ItemsSource="{Binding AccountManagers}"
          DisplayMemberPath="UserName"
          SelectedValuePath="UserCode"
          Width="250"
```

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here.
I don't get any errors at run/load time.
The ComboBox displays without any contents in the drop down.
(It's empty).

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: for a start you should have your list of account managers on a VM using an observable Collection, second you can't bind you attributes only properties

Comment: MikeT:  Can you please explain in a little more detail? I'm not quite following "can't bind attributes, only properties." Thx

Comment: to point you in the right direction all binding errors are reported to the output window, they don't cause breaks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is simple.
Change

```
public List<AccountManager> AccountManagers;
```

to this

```
public List<AccountManager> AccountManagers { get; set; }
```

and make sure that you have these in your MainWindow constructor

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //Setup Account managers here
    DataContext = this;
}
```

you can only bind to properties not fields and you need to ensure the proper data context

Comment: Thanks NR: I wasn't setting my DataContext in my constructor. Works fine now.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it!

Answer (score 5):

your making a couple of mistakes

firstly you're not following MVVM

the correct MVVM should look as follows

```
public class AccountManager
{
   public long UserCode { get; set; }
   public string UserName { get; set; }
}
public class AccountManagersVM
{
   public ObservableCollection<AccountManager> AccountManagers{ get; set; }

}
```

then no need for changes to the code behind you just need to use the DataContext which can be set directly or via a binding

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:AccountManagersVM />
</Window.DataContext>
ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AccountManagers}"
          DisplayMemberPath="UserName"
          SelectedValuePath="UserCode"
          Width="250"
```

Second attributes/fields  can't be bound only properties

eg `public long UserCode { get; set; }` will work but `public long UserCode;`
wont